# Tkinter: background image problems

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a game for a competition and it's coming along pretty nicely so far. I made an image I want to use as a background, so I loaded and placed it the same as I did with the player image:

```
self.bg_1=PhotoImage(file="bg_space.gif")

bg1=self.create_image(0,0,image=self.bg_1)
```

This is the result: 
[image: bg error]

It only shows a quarter of the whole image. Is the file size too big? Did I code something wrong?

I tried making four images, one for each quarter of the image, and position them in the correct spots on the canvas. This turned out even worse, and I think only showed a quarter of those as well.

I'm pretty puzzled about this, and would appreciate anyone's input on this.
thanks

Comment: Please post bg_space.gif

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Z3orsXg.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the image is centered on the coordinate you give it. To change this, set the parameter `anchor` to `"nw"` (northwest):

```
bg1=self.create_image(0,0,image=self.bg_1, anchor="nw")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryan, you saved the day again!